# iam trying to integrate precreated website to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i just started to integrate my working website to word press .. but i have a little problem when i move navbar menu into header.php as you can see in the end of code , there is unordered list with list items ...how can i link these menu items to existing pages to work in word press

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta char set="<?php bloginfo('charset');?>">
    <title>
   some code goes here.......
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="venuetravel.php">Venue/Travel</a></li>
                     <li><a href="schedule.php">Schedule</a></li>
                              </ul>
```

thank you in advance...

Comment: You can simply just create the pages in the backend, name the pages as in your code, and wordpress will do the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can't add menu in wordpress like this you have done.you need to go to wordpress admin panel and then go to appearance -> menu and add the menu items you want to appear in pages of your site.

Thanks

Comment: you are absolutely right ...but actually for some reason i need to do it like this so how can i trigger the path to my pages using php code(maybe phph functions) that work for wordpress...